# iOS UI testing driven from environment other than OS X

Tags: ios, testing

I am looking for a tool to test iPhone app UIs and would prefer to have a test driver executes tests from a Windows or Linux environment, by sending commands to the test server on the phone via HTTP. Is there anything out there like that?

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to find anything that allows me to test the GUI automatically on a non-OSX environment.

There are alternatives to the Automation part of Instruments.
You might for example use FoneMonkey http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/231901614

You write that you want to use HTTP to send commands to some sort of magic TestServer running on the devices. I think that this will be very much impossible on a non-rooted phone, and you would at the same time be unable to get the test results automatically, ( asking via. HTTP whether a button is on the screen seems... Wrong ).

What are your reasons for this setup?

Anyway, long story short, my answer is going to be no, there is nothing like what you request out there, and I suggest you look into Apples [Automation Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/AutomationInstrument/AutomationInstrument.html) which allow you to do quite a lot of nifty stuff

Good luck!